# Sstable upgrade required after scylla version upgrade?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have checked scylla upgrade documentations found the steps.
https://docs.scylladb.com/upgrade/upgrade-opensource/upgrade-guide-from-2.1-to-2.2/upgrade-guide-from-2.1-to-2.2-rpm/.
As cassandra after binary upgrade we need to do perform sstable upgrade by nodetool upgradesstable command but in scylla there is no any step to perform. Is it required? or nodetool upgradesstable command not supported in scylla? please help

Answer (score 5):

There's no requirement to run any tool. The existing sstables will be naturally upgraded via compaction.

Comment: So once binary upgraded no need to do any other steps except starting the scylla services as per upgrade steps right?. here compaction means auto-compaction or major compaction required?

Comment: @Pandy, Avi referred to the background compaction process, no need to run major compaction.